# Can Oracle ADF Application deploy or run in Jboss

Tags: jboss5.x, oracle-adf

I found out that some of the developer able to deploy their ADF application in JBoss appServer. However, I read in oracle support system documentation it stated that ADF application is not supported in JBoss, Tomcat etc.

Currently I'm doing a research on whether Oracle ADF is feasible to deploy/develop using JBoss server. I know the best is to use weblogic server.

So can anyone help to clear my doubt on this question? Appreciate a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADF is based in JSF, which is the standard for Java EE, so it should be handled by every Java EE container (no matter if it's not an Oracle product). This link should avoid any doubts: [ADF Essentials deployment](http://technology.amis.nl/2012/09/25/develop-and-deploy-adf-applications-free-of-charge-using-the-new-adf-essentials/) (Don't worry if it talks only about ADF Essentials. Basically it is a subset of the full version). 
And here you've got some hints on doing that: [Deploy ADF on JBoss5](https://blogs.oracle.com/jruiz/entry/deploying_an_adf_11g_applicati)

Comment: alright thanks for your info! will try to read up that articles. :)

Comment: Glad to help :) ! But please, it's a common practice to vote or accept the answer if you are satisfied here in SO.